# forms not switching on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I'm trying to use this code from jsfiddle ([jsfiddle.net/xBxv4](http://jsfiddle.net/xBxv4/)) to switch forms based on a drop down menu selection but it's not working at all. I tried moving the script to HEAD, right before FORM starts, right before BODY closes, etc. but it just doesn't perform the switch. I verified the sample jsfiddle code works with the jQuery 1.10.2 codebase so it's not a codebase issue. My code below has some CodeIgniter functions injected, but the id and class HTML attributes are appropriately defined.

Any ideas why my form is not switching on selection?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

```
    <title>add property</title>

    <!-- Loading: jQuery -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="Javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="Javascript"></script>

    <!-- Loading, Setting Up: Form, Form Validation Plugin -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.form.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="Javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="Javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.validation.settings.js" type="text/javascript" language="Javascript"></script>

    <!-- Loading: Respond.js (Old IE Media Queries) -->
    <!-- Note: Respond.js only understands min-width / max-width media queries -->
    <script src="assets/js/respond.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="Javascript"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <h2>add a property</h2>

    <?if($this->session->flashdata('flashError')):?>
    <div class='flashError'>
        <?=$this->session->flashdata('flashError')?>
    </div>
    <?endif?>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
    $('#property_campaign').on('change', function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $('#forsale_form').hide();
        $('#forrent_form').hide();
        $('#foreclosure_form').hide();
        $('#portfolio_form').hide();
        $('#undeveloped_form').hide();
        $('#' + val).show();
    });
    </script>

    <div id="addproperty_form_wrapper">

        <?=form_open(base_url().'/admin/property/add', array('id'=>'picker_form','class'=>'picker_form'))?>
            <p><span>*</span> = required field</p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label>property name <span>*</span></label>
                    <?=form_input('property_name', set_value('property_name'), 'id="property_name"')?>
                    <?=form_error('property_name')?>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>campaign <span>*</span></label>
                    <?=form_dropdown('property_campaign', array('forsale' => 'for sale', 'forrent' => 'for rent', 'foreclosure' => 'foreclosure', 'portfolio' => 'portfolio', 'undeveloped' => 'undeveloped'), set_value('property_campaign'), 'id="property_campaign"')?>
                    <?=form_error('property_campaign')?>
                </li>
            </ul>
        <?=form_close()?>

        <!-- add for sale property form -->
        <div id="forsale_formwrapper">
            <?=form_open(base_url().'/admin/property/add', array('id'=>'forsale_form','class'=>'hidden'))?>
                <h1>add a for sale property</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label>property's asking price <span>*</span></label>
                        <?=form_input('property_askingprice', set_value('property_askingprice'), 'id="property_askingprice"')?>
                        <?=form_error('property_askingprice')?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>property's blurb <span>*</span></label>
                        <?=form_textarea('property_blurb', set_value('property_blurb'),'id="property_blurb"')?>
                        <?=form_error('property_blurb')?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>property manager <span>*</span></label>
                        <?=form_dropdown('manager_id', array('989' => 'Michael Smith', 'forrent' => 'for rent', 'foreclosure' => 'foreclosure', 'undeveloped' => 'undeveloped'), set_value('manager_id'))?>
                        <?=form_error('property_manager')?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>property template <span>*</span></label>
                        <?=form_dropdown('template_id', array('9' => 'property X', 'forrent' => 'for rent', 'foreclosure' => 'foreclosure', 'undeveloped' => 'undeveloped'), set_value('template_id'))?>
                        <?=form_error('property_template')?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <?=form_reset('reset_form','reset')?>
                        <?=form_submit('add_forsaleproperty','add forsaleproperty','id="add_forsaleproperty"')?>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <?=form_close()?>
        </div>

        <!-- add parked property form -->
        <div id="forrent_formwrapper">
            <?=form_open(base_url().'/admin/property/add', array('id'=>'forrent_form','class'=>'hidden'))?>
                <h1>add a parked property</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label>parked property stuff <span>*</span></label>
                        <?=form_textarea('property_parkedstuff', set_value('property_parkedstuff'),'id="property_parkedstuff"')?>
                        <?=form_error('property_parkedstuff')?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <?=form_reset('reset_form','reset')?>
                        <?=form_submit('add_parkedproperty','add parkedproperty','id="add_parkedproperty"')?>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <?=form_close()?>
        </div>

        <!-- add mini-site property form -->
        <div id="foreclosure_formwrapper">
            <?=form_open(base_url().'/admin/property/add', array('id'=>'foreclosure_form','class'=>'hidden'))?>
                <h1>add a foreclosure property</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label>foreclosure property stuff <span>*</span></label>
                        <?=form_textarea('property_foreclosurestuff', set_value('property_foreclosurestuff'),'id="property_foreclosurestuff"')?>
                        <?=form_error('property_foreclosurestuff')?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <?=form_reset('reset_form','reset')?>
                        <?=form_submit('add_foreclosureproperty','add foreclosureproperty','id="add_foreclosureproperty"')?>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <?=form_close()?>           
        </div>

        <!-- add portfolio property form -->
        <div id="portfolio_formwrapper">
            <?=form_open(base_url().'/admin/property/add', array('id'=>'portfolio_form','class'=>'hidden'))?>
                <h1>add an portfolio property</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label>portfolio property stuff <span>*</span></label>
                        <?=form_textarea('property_portfoliostuff', set_value('property_portfoliostuff'),'id="property_portfoliostuff"')?>
                        <?=form_error('property_portfoliostuff')?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <?=form_reset('reset_form','reset')?>
                        <?=form_submit('add_portfolioproperty','add portfolioproperty','id="add_portfolioproperty"')?>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <?=form_close()?>       
        </div>

        <!-- add undeveloped property form -->
        <div id="undeveloped_formwrapper">
            <?=form_open(base_url().'/admin/property/add', array('id'=>'undeveloped_form','class'=>'hidden'))?>
                <h1>add an undeveloped property</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label>undeveloped property stuff <span>*</span></label>
                        <?=form_textarea('property_undevelopedstuff', set_value('property_undevelopedstuff'),'id="property_undevelopedstuff"')?>
                        <?=form_error('property_undevelopedstuff')?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <?=form_reset('reset_form','reset')?>
                        <?=form_submit('add_undevelopedproperty','add undevelopedproperty','id="add_undevelopedproperty"')?>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <?=form_close()?>           
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like two issues. First, put your code in a dom ready handler so you can be sure the element exists:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#property_campaign').on('change', function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $('#forsale_form').hide();
        $('#forrent_form').hide();
        $('#foreclosure_form').hide();
        $('#portfolio_form').hide();
        $('#undeveloped_form').hide();
        $('#' + val).show();
    });
});
```

Second, it looks like you have a dropdown with (for example) an `option` with the value `forsale`. In your javascript function, you do this:

```
$('#forsale_form').hide();
```

But then use the value to show the same form, but the value is `forsale`, so

```
$('#' + val).show();
```

becomes:

```
$('#forsale').show();
```

Which doesn't exist. So, you can either change your dropdown to have the right values, or change your javascript to this:

```
$('#' + val + '_form').show();
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! Worked like a charm. You just ended 8 days of misery for me. Much appreciated.